# How to duplicate multiple columns in a dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, duplicates

I would like to expand the size of this dataframe from 1 column to 1,000 columns with same content.

I think it's a basic question but I can't figure out the solution. Thanks for answering.

[image: 5*1 size]